# Main using outdated classes

Tags: c++, makefile

The class methods that my main is using are outdated. I have updated the methods to cout to the terminal, but nothing is being displayed. I put a cout before and after the method call, and both of them are being printed. This makes me think I'm compiling wrong.

I have attached my Makefile:

```
RM = rm -f
SRCPATH = .
SRC = actors/actor.h  controllers/AiController.h controllers/Controller.h \
controllers/PlayerController.h states/BrawlState.h states/DrinkState.h \
states/IdleState.h states/IStateCallback.h states/MineState.h \
states/SingState.h states/SleepState.h states/state.h states/statemachine.h \
resources/dynamicarray.h resources/hashmap.h resources/hashnode.h \
resources/heap.h resources/queue.h resources/stack.h resources/vector3d.h
TESTNAME = test
TESTSRC = main.cpp
#
retest: re test

clean:
    -$(RM) *.o
    -$(RM) *~
    -$(RM) \#*
    -$(RM) *.core
    -$(RM) *.gch

fclean: clean
    -$(RM) $(TESTNAME)

re: fclean

test: 
    g++ $(SRC) $(TESTSRC) -Wall -Werror -std=c++0x -o $(TESTNAME)
```

Comment: Do you only have header files, or are there `.cpp` files too?

Comment: I only have header files because they are classes.

Comment: That doesn't actually make any sense, but OK. You need to make `test` depend on all the headers, plus `main.cpp`. Right not `test` has no dependencies.

Comment: First, it's a terrible idea to name a program `test`.  `test` is a shell built-in and will be very confusing to people if they try to run it without a path.  Second, this makefile is not very useful, since it recompiles _everything_ any time _anything_ changes.  What's the point?  You might as well just write a shell script.  It's crazy how often I'm seeing this type of thing these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `test` target depend on all the source files and headers, so that a change in any one of them triggers a re-compilation next time you run `make test`:

```
test: $(TESTSRC) $(SRC)
    g++ $(SRC) $(TESTSRC) -Wall -Werror -std=c++0x -o $(TESTNAME)
```